# What is (a) Könnin kuokkamies?

Tags: mythical-creatures, finnish

It seems to be some kind of robotic/mechanical entity, but that's pretty much all I could gather from googling around.

There is a Wikipedia page on the matter: [here](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nnin_kuokkamies), but it is in Finnish, which I, unfortunately, can't read. The picture there piques my curiosity a bit, showing something completely unanthropomorphic (but to be fair, mythical beings don't have to be anthropomorphic).

There is also a number of translations of the eponymous Korpiklaani song, mostly giving an impression of a silent mechanical worker - although I'm not sure whether it *can't* talk or just *doesn't like* to. Not much about the actual shape can be inferred. Also, I don't know how faithful this is to the original myths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kuokammies means "Ploughman", and Könni is a Finnish Family name. So "The Ploughman of Könni".

It's also a [song by a Finnish Band](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/Koennin-Kuokkamies-H-o-e-man-Koenni.html), lyrics in English provided.

Lyrics remind me of [Johannes Von Saaz' "Death and the Plowman"](https://www.bookdepository.com/Death-Ploughman-Johannes-Von-Saaz/9780413773036)

Edit: I just copied the Finnish text you linked into Google Translate and got this:

> Könn's dancer is one of Finland's most famous folk tales about the
>   mechanical "robot", which made Könn's master clear the land for
>   cultivation. According to the story, the man in the dungeon slammed
>   the ground and pushed the carts in the field. Passers-by raised a hand
>   and greeted him, but Kökkamies stayed silent, for the master did not
>   speak of having done it but working. The miserable fate of the royal
>   man was drowning in the ship's head when the sloppy slave fell asleep
>   and didn't turn it at the end of the field. Some investigators have
>   argued that this was a planned act, because the deaf man was
>   considered arrogant because of his silence.
>
> In some stories, Könne has a number of windbreakers, while others have
>   guts (feters) or weights. In other stories, however, deaf men are
>   becoming violent because of lost earnings. The pods traveled a lot and
>   the steam engine came in. It was hardly a strange thing, as Mr A.
>   Wasastjerna, the founder and partner of Tampella, made his spinning
>   gear at a workshop on a riverboat steam engine. However, the machine
>   was broken during the test run and repaired at Könn's place.

Comment: The explanation of the name is helpful, thank you. I'm aware of the song - tbh, that's how I learned of the entity and got most of the information from. Could you elaborate on the mythological background and properties of the creature a bit? It would add greatly to the answer, I believe.

Comment: Nevermind, see edit, that should clear things up.

Comment: I will wait a day or two before accepting the answer, in case anything else appears.

Comment: Also regarding the name Könni, they were a famous family of smiths and clockmakers in 1700-1800s. There is a Finnish [wikipedia page](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nnin_mestarit) about them as well.